# Angular Material paginator hides the buttons and number of pages by the global background color

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

[image]
[image]

I implemented [material paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview) and the number of items per page and buttons(next and previous) are hided by the global backgroud color. I have attached 2 images and global background color of one of them is deactivated and can see the number of pages and buttons(next and previous).

I need to keep the background color and make visible the number of items per page and next and previous buttons.

I did read few releted articles and made few changes for example,

```
::ng-deep my-style-class {
   background-color: unset;
}
```

All of them were not worked.

Can you please give me a suggestion to make visible number of pages and next, previous buttons without disabing the global background color.

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproducible example to troubleshoot? There are many ways to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not working is that this code is expecting a class called mat-paginator and mat-icon-button.

```
::ng-deep .mat-paginator .mat-icon-button
{
  background-color: YourColor;
}
```

Comment: Above code segment set the color for next and previous buttons of the mat paginater but still the background color covers the items per page and next, previous buttons.